# How to update complex jsonb column?

Tags: postgresql, update, json, postgresql-9.5

I have a table with following definition:

```
create table json_test (
    filter_data jsonb);
```

and i insert to it values like this:

```
'{"task_packets": [
    {
        "state": "PROCEEDING",
        "task_id": 1001
    },
    {
        "state": "REVERTING",
        "task_id": 1002
    }
]}'
```

Now I want to update this `jsonb` column to:

```
'{"task_packets": [
    {
        "state": "DONE",
        "task_id": 1001
    },
    {
        "state": "REVERTING",
        "task_id": 1002
    }
]}'
```

i.e. I want to change state for value with specified `task_id` inside array of task_packets. I suggest somehow to use `jsonb_set()` function in combination with `#-` operator (first delete value from array, then append to it with updated state).
How can I do it?

Comment: Is the array element you want to modify guaranteed to be in first position? Actually, this should probably be a normalized design instead of a `jsonb` column ...

Comment: No, it's not guaranteed to be first. Actually, i've solved that probem by unpacking json array to elements  with function jsonb_array_elements, thewn filtering, and then array_agg function. Like this:
`select jsonb_agg(l.*) || '{"task_id" : 1002, "state" : "REVERTING"}' 
from jsonb_array_elements('[{"task_id" : 1001, "state" : "PROCEEDING"}, {"task_id" : 1002, "state" : "REVERTING"}, {"task_id" : 1003, "state" : "REVERTING"}]') as l 
where (l->>'task_id')::int <> 1002`

this code yelds initial array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To **`SELECT`**:

```
SELECT *
     , jsonb_set(filter_data
               , '{task_packets}'
               , (SELECT jsonb_agg(CASE WHEN elem->>'task_id' = '1001'
                                   THEN jsonb_set(elem, '{state}', '"DONE"')
                                   ELSE elem END)
                  FROM   jsonb_array_elements(filter_data->'task_packets') elem)
                ) AS filter_data_new
FROM   json_test jt
WHERE  jt.filter_data @> '{"task_packets": [{"task_id": 1001}]}';
```

Use a ***`LATERAL` join*** or a **correlated subquery** (like demonstrated). This exclude the possibility of multiple matching rows that might be lumped together incorrectly in a plain join.

To **`UPDATE`**:

```
UPDATE json_test
SET    filter_data
     = jsonb_set(filter_data
               , '{task_packets}'
               , (SELECT jsonb_agg(CASE WHEN elem->>'task_id' = '1001'
                                   THEN jsonb_set(elem, '{state}', '"DONE"')
                                   ELSE elem END)
                  FROM   jsonb_array_elements(filter_data->'task_packets') elem)
                )
WHERE  filter_data @> '{"task_packets": [{"task_id": 1001}]}';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1ctf3fX4)

To make this fast for big tables, be sure to have an appropriate **index**, ideally a `jsonb_path_ops` index. See:

- [What's the proper index for querying structures in arrays in Postgres jsonb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499266/whats-the-proper-index-for-querying-structures-in-arrays-in-postgres-jsonb/27708358#27708358)

##### Aside

This would be much more efficient in a normalized DB design with a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE task_packets (
  task_id int PRIMARY KEY
, state text NOT NULL
-- or: state_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES state(state_id) ...
);
```

Among other things, we can have a PK constraint enforcing unique `task_id` numbers. And the `UPDATE` you want is trivial.

Comment: Thx, your answer if full enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This helped a lot, however I had to update multiple keys in the array at once and went with the 9.5+ concatenate shortcut **||**.

```
update public.contactsdb
set data = (select jsonb_set(data, '{Contacts}', jsonb_agg(
    elem || '{"Summary": "A User", "Email":"thisemail@is.bad"}'))
    from jsonb_array_elements(data->'Contacts') elem )
  where id in (select id from contactsdb,
   jsonb_array_elements(data->'Contacts') as elems where elems->'Summary' is not null)
```

sorry for the formatting in the block. i can't get it right. mod have at it

Comment: I'm not sure if your parenthesis are correct. If I try to reformat your code I am under the impression that parts of the statement are closed `)` in the wrong place. Does this statement actually work?

Comment: Strange. Yes, it does work for me. it is taken directly after running minus some field and value redacting only.

Comment: @hot2use i did mess up the where table orginally. just fixed that, but otherwise i just double checked it and it is exactly the same as the one i used but with redacting.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
update 
    json_test 
set
    filter_data  = 
        jsonb_set(
            filter_data ,
            array['task_packets', elem_index::text, 'state'],
            '"DONE"'::jsonb,
            true)
from (
    select 
     pos- 1 as elem_index
    id 
    from 
        json_test, 
        jsonb_array_elements(filter_data ) with ordinality arr(elem, pos)
    where
       elem->>'task_id' = '1001'
    ) sub
where sub.id=id
```